# python AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to read in a csv file of forex data into my code but I get this error. The csv file clearly has a date column so I am confused

here is my code

```
data = pd.read_csv('GBPJPY.csv')

data.columns = ['date','open','high','low','close','volume']

data = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)

data = data.set_index(data.Date)

data = ['open','high','low','close','volume']

price = data.close.iloc[:100]
```

here is some of the csv file

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
08.03.2018 00:00:00.000 GMT-0500,147.464,147.466,147.405,147.418,169.75
08.03.2018 00:01:00.000 GMT-0500,147.418,147.430,147.404,147.412,234.21
08.03.2018 00:02:00.000 GMT-0500,147.412,147.419,147.398,147.411,179.43
08.03.2018 00:03:00.000 GMT-0500,147.411,147.424,147.403,147.410,149.62
08.03.2018 00:04:00.000 GMT-0500,147.410,147.433,147.407,147.411,188.22
08.03.2018 00:05:00.000 GMT-0500,147.412,147.412,147.392,147.407,209.49
08.03.2018 00:06:00.000 GMT-0500,147.407,147.413,147.397,147.410,216.6
08.03.2018 00:07:00.000 GMT-0500,147.410,147.425,147.404,147.425,236.67
08.03.2018 00:08:00.000 GMT-0500,147.425,147.433,147.423,147.427,204.06
08.03.2018 00:09:00.000 GMT-0500,147.427,147.432,147.400,147.421,184.34
08.03.2018 00:10:00.000 GMT-0500,147.421,147.422,147.411,147.413,164.26
08.03.2018 00:11:00.000 GMT-0500,147.413,147.414,147.397,147.413,107.21
08.03.2018 00:12:00.000 GMT-0500,147.413,147.442,147.412,147.440,159.66
08.03.2018 00:13:00.000 GMT-0500,147.441,147.445,147.423,147.425,154.93
08.03.2018 00:14:00.000 GMT-0500,147.424,147.433,147.424,147.433,120.57
08.03.2018 00:15:00.000 GMT-0500,147.434,147.448,147.434,147.435,188.68
08.03.2018 00:16:00.000 GMT-0500,147.434,147.454,147.434,147.453,229.66
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you renamed columns here in second line

```py
data.columns = ['date','open','high','low','close','volume']
```

use new name `date` instead of `Date` like

```py
...
data.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date)
...
```